# Use Cloud SDK in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, sails.js

I followed the guide here - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing

So my lifecycle.test.js looks like this:

```
var sails = require('sails');

// Before running any tests...
before(function(done) {

  // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift, even if you have a bunch of assets.
  this.timeout(5000);

  sails.lift({
    // Your sails app's configuration files will be loaded automatically,
    // but you can also specify any other special overrides here for testing purposes.

    // For example, we might want to skip the Grunt hook,
    // and disable all logs except errors and warnings:
    hooks: { grunt: false },
    log: { level: 'warn' },

  }, function(err) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }

    // here you can load fixtures, etc.
    // (for example, you might want to create some records in the database)

    return done();
  });
});

// After all tests have finished...
after(function(done) {

  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  // (e.g. you might want to destroy the records you created above)

  sails.lower(done);

});
```

However in my test I am not able to use `Cloud`. I thought this was available to me because I saw in test suites here that they use `Cloud` - https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/tree/master/test/suites

Do i have to modify my `lifecycle.test.js` to use `Cloud`?